# T-SQL syntax on creating temp table from union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

This runs find by itself

```
(select * from #T1 
 union
 select * from  #T2)
```

This does not (added first line):

```
select * 
into #T3 
from
    (select * from #T1 
     union
     select * from  #T2)
```

It throws a syntax error.

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is invalid syntax, you need `alias` while using result set from the derived table :

```
select * into #t3
from  (select col1, col2, . . . 
       from #t1
       union all
       select col1, col2, . . 
       from #t2
      ) t; --- alias missing
```

Comment: yep, it worked.  for some reason my query here in this comment didn't give the expected row count (did not match sum)....  any ideas why, you may share if you like.  i will accept answer shortly: Select * into #T3 from
(select * from #T1 Union
Select * from  #T2) as AAA

Comment: got it.   union all doesn't remove duplicates.  i had duplicates.  that's why your query worked and mine didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery.  Just add the `into` after the first `select`:

```
select *
into #T3
from #T1 
union
select *
from #T2;
```

Note that you should use `union all` unless you really do want to incur the overhead for removing duplicates.